# Is Startups.com part of the SO family?

Tags: discussion

[Startups.com](http://startups.com) is very similar to StackExchange sites in terms of style. Is it part of the family?

Comment: Seems like this isn't off-topic until _after_ you already know the answer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Also http://answers.onstartups.com/ *is* an SE 2.0 site so that's on topic.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [StackExchange 1.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) site. Although StackExchange is similar to StackOverflow, and based upon it, they are two separate entities, and SE questions should be asked at [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a site using the stackoverflow engine, though not affiliated with stackoverflow itself as the meta/SU/SF/SO siblings are.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not one of the official sites (i.e. not part of the StackOverflow trilogy - now quadrology). It is however based on the [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) platform, designed by [Fog Creek Software](http://www.fogcreek.com/), the creators of SO (i.e. Jeff, Joel, and co.).